# Could someone explain to me what this code does?

Tags: c

Recently we received this code fragment, and I really have no idea what it does.
Could someone please help me and maybe explain to me what the code actually does?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 29
#define C_SPACE 26
#define C_COMMA 27
#define C_STOP 28

int getcc() {
  int c, haveSpace = 0;
  while(isspace(c=getchar())) haveSpace = 1;
  if(haveSpace) return (ungetc(c,stdin),C_SPACE);
  else if(c>=’a’ && c<=’z’) return c-’a’;
  else if(c>=’A’ && c<=’Z’) return c-’A’;
  else if(c==’,’) return C_COMMA;
  else if(c==’.’) return C_STOP;
  else if(c==EOF) return EOF;
  else return getcc();
}
```

Comment: You have to learn how to use a debugger or you will never learn to code. Even without the debugger, you can walk the code. What is the output if the value of c is a 'b'? What about a 'C'?

Comment: Looks like a simple tokenizer. I returns a single code for any string of whitespace, another code for letters after case folding, and more codes for other punctuation.

Comment: The comparisons to the character literals are actually comparing to the ASCII codes for those literals. Does that help?

Comment: that did not help me that much jalynn2, i am very sorry. I am pretty new to all of this scripting

Comment: It's not "scripting". Are you new to C? If you step through line by line, what's the first line that gives you trouble?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker , so this fragment takes a string, breaks it into pieces (commas points etc ) and then thats it?

Comment: yes @lurker i am very new to c. The first line that gives me trouble starts with haveSpace = 0.

Comment: `int c, haveSpace = 0;` declares two `int` values, `c` and `haveSpace`. It also pre-initializes `haveSpace` to 0. You really should go through a C tutorial. Otherwise, someone's going to need to walk through this code almost line by line just to teach the basics of C, and that's not really the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returning a code for the next alphabetic character read from stdin:

```
int getcc() {
  int c, haveSpace = 0;
  //Read characters until you get one that is not white space. If any white space read, remember it
  while(isspace(c=getchar())) haveSpace = 1;
  //if a space was read, put the non-space back to stdin, and return 26.
  if(haveSpace) return (ungetc(c,stdin),C_SPACE);
  //if the character is a lower-case letter, return the index into the alphabet: a=0, b=1, etc.
  else if(c>=’a’ && c<=’z’) return c-’a’;
  //if the character is an upper-case letter, return the index into the alphabet: A=0, B=1, etc.
  else if(c>=’A’ && c<=’Z’) return c-’A’;
  //If the character is a comma, return 27
  else if(c==’,’) return C_COMMA;
  //If the character is a period, return 28
  else if(c==’.’) return C_STOP;
  //if at end of file, return EOF
  else if(c==EOF) return EOF;
  //if any other character, skip it by calling the function again and returning the result.
  else return getcc();
}
```